# Convert .webm to .mp4

Tags: java, mp4, webm

I would like to convert a `.webm` to `.mp4`. There is any libraries which can do it in Java? Or anything else?

To summarize, I'm actually developing an application which can extract the sound from YouTube or Vimeo video (using the lib vget).

The problem is the return, I get a file which is encoded `.webm`.

Comment: Hey Victor, I see that some people voted to close your question because they think your it is off-topic on Stack Overflow because you're asking about a library recommendation. I think they're wrong. But to avoid this you could simply ask about how to solve this in Java, without mentioning libraries.

Comment: I retract my **re-open** vote. It will be agreeable when you make a real **programming** / **technical** question. For example with Youtube the direct links to the audio part (mp3 or m4a) of a video can be found in the page's source code (after specific text extraction & cleaning up its html entities... etc). Also consider using some FFmpeg executable as an external `Process` to achieve format conversion.

Answer (score 3):

**----Update 2021----**

Please check Jave 2 https://github.com/a-schild/jave2

---

You can convert both Audio and Video to almost any format using FFMPEG under the hood https://github.com/a-schild/jave2/blob/master/Examples.md

**----Update 2016 ( deprecated )----**

You can have a look at `JAVE`([Download](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/index.php))

> The JAVE (Java Audio Video Encoder) library is Java wrapper on the
> ffmpeg project. Developers can take take advantage of JAVE to
> transcode audio and video files from a format to another. In example
> you can transcode an AVI file to a MPEG one, you can change a DivX
> video stream into a (youtube like) Flash FLV one, you can convert a
> WAV audio file to a MP3 or a Ogg Vorbis one, you can separate and
> transcode audio and video tracks, you can resize videos, changing
> their sizes and proportions and so on. Many other formats, containers
> and operations are supported by JAVE.

Although i have not used it for `.webm` i am sure that there is a workaround using this Library . It almost supports everything.

---

Examples and tutorials [here](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/jave/manual.php)

Example converting `AVI` to a youtube-like `FLV` movie, with an embedded `MP3` audio stream:

```
File source = new File("source.avi");
File target = new File("target.flv");
AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
audio.setCodec("libmp3lame");
audio.setBitRate(new Integer(64000));
audio.setChannels(new Integer(1));
audio.setSamplingRate(new Integer(22050));
VideoAttributes video = new VideoAttributes();
video.setCodec("flv");
video.setBitRate(new Integer(160000));
video.setFrameRate(new Integer(15));
video.setSize(new VideoSize(400, 300));
EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
attrs.setFormat("flv");
attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
attrs.setVideoAttributes(video);
Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
encoder.encode(source, target, attrs);
```

Comment: Actually, it seems like JAVE offers no support for the "webm" format,  it is not listed on their manual. I have the same question as OP and am thus at a loss now.

Comment: @Isaiah Lucky you , we have made a new project called Jave 2 :)

https://github.com/a-schild/jave2